# How to push the value of radio buttons to array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and I'm trying to create a quiz dynamically filling the radio buttons and storing them in an array. I have a couple of issues.  I have the questions and radio buttons working.  The values selected are not coming back into the array 'selections'. I have tried a few things which I have found here and elsewhere. It shows a value of "on" or "undefined" for the array when I make my selection. Due to this my Alert for "Make a Selection is not working it simply allows you to move to the next question.

Here is my code.

```js
function billQuestions() {
      const myBills = [
          { question: 'Who is on the One Dollar Bill?',
            choices: ['Thomas Jefferson', 'George Washington'],
            correctAnswer: 'George Washington' },
          { question: 'Who is on the Fifty Dollar Bill?',
            choices: ['George Washington', 'John Quincy Adams'],
            correctAnswer: 'John Quincy Adams' },
          ];


      let questionCounter = 0;     /* Tracks question number */
      let selections = [];         /* Array containing user choices */
      let quiz = $('#quiz');       /* Quiz div object */


/* Pulls the length of the Choices Objects */
     getChoicesLength();
function getChoicesLength () {
     let clength = Object.keys(myBills[1].choices).length;
return(clength);
}

/* If no user selection, progress is stopped */
      if(!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) 
          {alert('Please make a selection!');
      } else {questionCounter++;
          displayNext();
        }
      });


/* Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs */
    function createRadios(index) {
        let radioList = $('<ul>');
        let input = $('');
           clength = getChoicesLength();

    for (let i = 0; i < clength; i++) {
        input = $('<li><input type="radio" name="answer" />' + 
                myBills[index].choices[i] + '</input></li>');
        radioList.append(input);
     }
  return radioList;
}

/* Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array */
function choose() {
  selections[questionCounter] = $('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
}

/* Displays next requested element */
function displayNext() {
  quiz.fadeOut(function() {
    $('#question').remove();

    clength = getChoicesLength();  

    if(questionCounter < clength){
      let nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
      quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
      if ((isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
        $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', 
            true);
        console.log(selections);
        console.log(questionCounter);
      }
```

Comment: You should maybe find a better way to indent your code. This is hard to read. Also, this is too much code. Please limit the code to the part that is essential for your question, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will work on that

Comment: I see you are using Jquery. Maybe try https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ `.serialize()`

Comment: I will look at it.  Thank you